# TFS2017 nuget restore try to connect to nuget.org

Tags: tfs, nuget

I have a TFS server without internet access. I configure my own nuget package feeds in TFS and I try to restore packages of my solution only from this feed. But when I start Nuget restore build step, nuget try to connect to nuget.org and the connection failed. I don't understand how prevent this attempt of unnecessary connection ?

[image: Nuget build step configuration]

[image: Build error message]

Comment: How's your build definition like? Try to add `NuGet Tool Installer` task before` Nuget Restore` to see whether it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem. In fact, I think NugetRestore task try to connect to nuget.org to get the last version of nuget.exe.

I skirt the problem with use version 0.* of NugetRestore task and specif the version of nuget to use.

[image: Nuget Installer 0.*]

Answer (score 0):

You can control your NuGet sources in the Nuget.Config file. Create a file "Nuget.config" in the same folder as your solution file. Within the config file, you can clear all source and define your own. As an example, you can set your packageSource as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="ThirdParty Nuget Repository" value="http://localNuget/artifactory/api/nuget/ThirdParty" />    
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

The <clear/> element will clear your existing Nuget sources and the <add> element will set up a new local Nuget Source for you.

More on Nuget config file can be read at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file

Comment: I try your solution but there are always a connection to nuget.org... I don't understand why...

Comment: Can you list the files in your solution directory please